# Mark: outstanding (as in: not yet known)

Tags: meaning, writing, synonyms

I’m updating my tabular CV for an application and I’d like to include my master thesis even though it’s not yet finished (soon!) and marked. So I’d like to write that the mark is still outstanding but I fear that if I simply write

> Master thesis: ‹topic›
>   Supervisor: ‹supervisor›
>   Mark: outstanding

this could be misconstrued to mean that the result is in, and that it’s outstanding (as in: spectacular). What can I say here instead? It should be as salient as possible, single word preferred. I specifically want to avoid writing half a sentence.

Comment: I've been given *OUTSTANDING* once for a grade that wasn't yet out. Honestly, it depends on the context and your audience. In many English-speaking academic situations outside the US, *outstanding* would not at all be ambiguous. The same would go for *mark*. I daresay *outstanding* would only be considered ambiguous in a context such as *Rating: outstanding*.

Comment: In both Canada and the UK, I would say it’s quite ambiguous — I thought of ‘remarkably impressive’ as the main meaning of *outstanding* before I ever went to the states.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go for “**pending**” (or, longer, “still pending”).

Answer (score 4):

I agree, using `outstanding` here is quite ambiguous.

I would use `Awaiting mark` or `Pending mark` - they are both clear and direct. (You can alternatively substitute `mark` with `grade`.)

Answer (score 3):

I think something such as 'Awaiting Results' would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

**To be received**, or **to be decided**?

This fits into a pattern of common phrases: *to be confirmed*, *to be announced*, *to be decided*, which are standard enough that in many institutions they are given just as *tbc*, *tba*, *tbd*.  *To be received* is less standard than these, but should be well-understood since it clearly invokes this well-known template.